# django-rest-framework many-to-many relations. Create if not exists

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I try to send the following data to my django application:

```
{
    "hashtags": ["hashtag"], 
    "title": "title", 
    "message": "message"
}
```

and i get this response:

```
{
    "hashtags": [
        {
            "non_field_errors": [
                "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have the following view defined in `views.py`

```
class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = IsAuthorizedOwnerOrReadOnly,
```

the models are defined like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ambassador = models.OneToOneField("User")
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    hashtags = models.ManyToManyField("PostHashtags", related_query_name="posts")

    title = models.CharField(max_length=TEXT_SHORT, null=True, blank=True)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=TEXT_MIDDLE, null=True, blank=True)


class PostHashtags(models.Model):
    hashtag = models.CharField(max_length=TEXT_SHORT, null=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.hashtag
```

and i define the serializers like this:

```
class PostHashtagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PostHashtags
        fields = ("hashtag",)


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hashtags = PostHashtagSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ("id", "hashtags", "title", "message",)
        read_only_fields = ("id", 'account_name',)
```

It seems like the hashtags are not created automatically using my current serialisation config. Is there a way to have my `hashtags` created if they do not yet exist, and if they do exist, have the `Post` use that same hashtag? In that case, how should my serialisers be defined?

**EDIT 1:**
After GwynBleidD's suggestions I now get the following error:

```
The `.create()` method does not support writable nestedfields by default.
Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer PostSerializer , or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.
```

Does anyone have a suggestion for such a create method?

**EDIT 2:** solved it using the following serialisers

```
class PostHashtagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hashtag = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = PostHashtags
        fields = ("hashtag",)


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hashtags = PostHashtagSerializer(many=True,)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ("ambassador", "hashtags", "title", "message",)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        hashtags_data = validated_data.pop('hashtags')

        post = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for hashtag in hashtags_data:
            ht = PostHashtags.objects.create()
            ht.hashtag = hashtag.get("hashtag")
            ht.save()
            post.hashtags.add(ht)
        post.save()
        return post
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hashtags are not string, but dict in that example. You have to submit:

```
{
    "hashtags": [{"hashtag": "hashtag"}], 
    "title": "title", 
    "message": "message"
}
```